# Browser event model

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, browser

Is there a good blog/wiki/documentation about various events that browsers have/expose ?
Like the order in which the events are fired, set of standard events etc ? I tried to google, but did not come across a good read even after many attempts. Thanks.

Comment: Rule of thumb: Google JavaScript related stuff and append "MDN" to get Mozilla Developer Network over the W3Schools crap.

Comment: IE is non-deterministic, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from [the W3C specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/) (which different browsers comply with to varying degrees), the standard reference for all things JavaScript and DOM is [MDC, the Mozilla Dev Connection (aka MDN, the Mozilla Dev Network)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).

For events, specifically, see the [DOM Event Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference#DOM_event_Reference) section.

For information about browser compatibility (super useful if you don't want to use a DOM library [*caveat emptor*]), check out [Quirksmode's](http://www.quirksmode.org) [event compatibility tables](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/).